# css hover causing unwanted div movement

Tags: css, hover

Somewhere along the way of developing [this](http://chrismepham.com/sites/newmjbox/index.php#) webpage I have managed to cause some unwanted shifting of the `#mainWrap` div that contains everything below the top navigation menu. When you hover over the "categories" link and the sub-menu appears it causes the `#mainWrap` div to shift downwards a few pixels. When you move the cursor away it shifts back upwards to its original position.

What might be causing this shifting?

Thanks

Comment: rather than providing a link to your webpage, you should create a jsfiddle for easy code access.

to me, it looks like the dropdown menu adds a margin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSS box model is in play here,In this code block:

```
 #cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a {
  background: #3f3f3f;
  border-color: #3f3f3f;
  padding-bottom: 13px;
  padding-top: 13px;
  top: -1px;
  z-index: 999;
  }
```

the hover adds `13px top-bottom margin` which increases the height, if your remove the padding then it would not shift.
Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Change height on `header` to `height: 167px;`

Answer (score 0):

firstly i would just fix categories hover event, a go from there...

## cssmenu ul li.has-sub:hover > a

remove this "top: 1px;"

if you have to move it up move up that

Comment: oh by the way u have a JS error   Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ; /sites/newmjbox/index.php#:3
Uncaught ReferenceError: loginFailed is not defined